# Constraint "ON DELETE RESTRICT" not being respected

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to learn sqlite and am following [this tutorial series](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net).
On the terminal, I started this tiny "example" database:

```
amrsa % sqlite3 example
SQLite version 3.32.3 2020-06-18 14:16:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
```

As a minimal working example to show the unexpected behavior I noticed, I need two tables:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE people(
   ...> person_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> name TEXT NOT NULL
   ...> );
```

and

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE jobs(
   ...> job_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> description TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...> person_id INTEGER,
   ...> FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
   ...> REFERENCES people (person_id)
   ...> ON UPDATE RESTRICT
   ...> ON DELETE RESTRICT
   ...> );
```

Now I add some rows to the tables:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO people(name)
   ...> VALUES("Bob"),("Mary");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM people;
1|Bob
2|Mary
```

Check: Bob and Mary are in the "people" table

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO jobs(description,person_id)
   ...> VALUES("job1",1),("job2",1),("job3",2);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM jobs;
1|job1|1
2|job2|1
3|job3|2
```

two jobs for Bob, and one for Mary: so far so good.

Now, let's try to delete "Bob".
It shouldn't be possible without deleting his jobs from the "jobs" table, given the constraint "ON DELETE RESTRICT", right?
However, it silently deletes the row:

```
sqlite> DELETE FROM people
   ...> WHERE person_id = 1;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM people;
2|Mary
sqlite> SELECT * FROM jobs;
1|job1|1
2|job2|1
3|job3|2
sqlite>
```

Confirmed that Bob is no longer in the "people" table.
Even worse, the jobs referring to him are still in the "jobs" table;
so it's like there was no constraint at all, right?

Am I doing something wrong here?
Or am I assuming something about constraints which is not right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQLite you must [enable foreign key support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) with:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

because it is disabled by default.

So even if you define foreign key constraints they are ignored, unless you enable them.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=09d7621b4a3ab0ea5654aa2f200697fb).

Comment: Thanks. I guess I overlooked something about that. It must also be in that tutorial I'm following...